# how can i send info from an email to a text file

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

So I am trying to find a way of parsing an email and sending the contents to a text file but I can only find ways to do it the other way around. It will then go onto a webpage so I'm wanting to do it in a web based language, could you recommend a language and what code I would need to make it work please?

Comment: Can you share code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>This is txt</h3>
  <!-- <?php
  // bool imap_savebody ( resource $imap_stream , mixed $file , 
  // int $msg_number [, string $part_number = "" 
  // [, int $options = 0 ]] )
  ?>  -->
  <embed src="myFile.txt">
 </body>


</html>

i tried using some php from the website you shared but im not very comfortable with php

Answer (score 1):

you could use php to connect to the mailserver, read out the mail and prepare it the way you need to store it in a database for example

PHP IMAP Extension
http://php.net/manual/de/book.imap.php

Comment: if im being honest, im not familiar with this, is there any other way to do it?